# How can an ion storm destroy a Borg cube?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

I recall at least two references in *Star Trek: Voyager* where a Borg cube was severely damaged or completely destroyed by an ion storm.

The Borg are probably the most technologically advanced species in the Star Trek universe. They possess such powerful technologies, like trans-warp travel and assimilation sting, that can't be stopped or blocked by anything. They've collected (assimilated) the technological knowledge of hundreds, if not thousands of technologically-advanced species.

How can it be that the same species is unable to create anything to stop, prevent or at least warn them of something as *simple* like an ion storm?

Comment: [One does not simply stop an ion storm](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/one-does-not-simply-walk-into-mordor).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, The Borg are not even close to the most advanced species in the *Star Trek* universe. I can think of a [few](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Species_8472) [examples](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Nacene) of [more](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Douwd) [powerful](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Q_%28species%29) [species](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Voth) just off the top of my head, and there are likely several I'm not thinking of right now. So we can discard that point.

Secondly, an [ion storm](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Ion_storm) is an incredibly powerful event. One might as well ask how human vehicles can be destroyed by lightning strikes, as we are the most technologically advanced species on our planet. The Borg are powerful, but they are not as powerful as the many wonders in the space they inhabit. There are [many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole) [forces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blazar) in [space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasar) that are more powerful than any corporeal species, like the Borg, could possibly hope to become. If a bank of phasers and proton torpedoes can destroy a Borg cube, then why shouldn't a massive storm in space do the job?

Comment: Species 8472, Cytherians, Kelvans (maybe), Aldeans (maybe), Voth, Srivani (maybe), Think Tank (various species), and Krenim, just to name a few.